# Getting an app in background on front using Selendroid

Tags: android, testing, automated-tests, selendroid

I am using `Selendroid` to test an `android` app. I am almost done with my test cases. But there is one situation when clicking on one button in the app opens up Play Store and I just want to go back to my app to continue my Test Cases. Please if anyone can help. I could not find anything related to that.

Comment: Do you finish your activity when you start an intent for Play Store?

Comment: Got it solved. I just needed to do driver.get(activity_name). Thanks for you input.